# Getting error while starting a container through docker in hyperledger fabric,how to resolve this?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

while starting containers by the command "sudo ./fabricNetwork.sh up" where fabricNetwork.sh is the shell script for starting containers I get the following error for the container "chaincode"
"Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
Error: failed to start containers: chaincode"
how to resolve this error

I tried changing the shebang line at the beginning of shell script from "#!/bin/bash" to "#!/bin/sh" but it gave me the error "./fabricNetwork.sh: 8: ./fabricNetwork.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected". Any ideas how to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

That error message looks like it is coming from the container itself, rather than your shell script. I'm not sure if it is wise to use sudo on your script,  according to different sources that I have read over the years. It is better if the owner of the shell script is added to the docker group, if you are running the script on Ubuntu.